# annoying beep in ms excel when switchin between workbooks

Tags: excel-2007, excel-2010, audio

For some reason, MS Excel 2010 makes a beep when I switch from one workbook to another in the same instance. It doesn't matter if I alt-tab or mouse click. Does anyone know how to turn this off? I have searched the internet and found similar complaints but no solution as of yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Excel but the specific sound event can be disabled in Windows.

> **Control Panel** > **Sound** > **Sounds** tab > **Default Beep** > set to **(None)** in the drop down.

Another workaround is to open Excel workbooks as separate instances.

> Right click on Excel on the task bar > select **Microsoft Excel 2010**.

This has the added benefit of letting you see workbooks side by side but precludes the ability to use advanced copy between workbooks (such as copy Formatting or Transpose).

Answer (score 4):

Found this answer and it worked:
In Excel go to **File** > **Options** > **Add-ins** > On the bottom drop-down, select **Manage "COM Add-ins"** > Click '**Go**'
Remove the Add-in listed and sound is gone

Answer (score 1):

I have not been able to find an answer as to why it does this for me also but I just went into my windows sounds and removed the sound that was going off and I never heard it again.  I do not remember which one I turned off (I think it was the default beep) because it was on my old computer with office 2007.  I would try trial and error and just remove that sound from that even.

**EDIT**

If you open up excel, Click the big button in top left and go to excel options at the bottom -> go to the Advanced tab -> The General section (towards the bottom), uncheck `Provide Feedback with sound`  That will turn off the sounds when switching tabs.

Comment: unfortunately i had already done that. `provide feedback with sound` is already unchecked..

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 8, the following solution works. Go to Settings (by swiping the right side of the screen)->Personalisation->Sounds and make it "No Sounds". This mutes all system sounds *except* when you're playing a song, etc. or more generally, when a program intentionally generates sound.

Answer (score 0):

I tried Misc's solution of disabling a COM Add-In in Excel. I tried the most useless looking COM Add-In listed on my machine, which was the Acer Cloud Excel Add-In. I unchecked it and the sound was gone.

Answer (score 0):

Misc's solution solved my problem; except I didn't need to disable everything there.  In my case, I only needed to disable "Daniel’s XL Toolbox" to stop it.  It hasn't been updated since 2018, and there's no option to disable it in its Settings.  It *is* on github, so somebody interested enough might fork it.  However, it only claims compatibility up to Excel 2016.  Too bad.  I'll just have to enable it by hand, if I want to export a range to a file, or am doing something sophisticated with ANOVA statistical analysis, or error bars on charts.

Look at me!  I'm a necroposting fool! :P